# Phonegap overlay image on camera preview for Android

Tags: android, html, cordova

Iv'e been search for days with out much success, all the phonegap overlays for Android topics fade out miserable with no real answer, so I'll just add another one to the mix! :)

Is there an easy way to manipulate the phonegap camera API so you can add a PNG to the camera preview?!

And return the URI as usual etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use absolute positioning to place a png with a transparent background over the image returned from the camera API.

Comment: Sorry, don't know if i was clear, but i need the PNG in the camera PREVIEW like a stencil. Not after the picture has been taken. Thanks for you reply though :)